# SSH-ing with the private key asks me for the password

Tags: ssh

This is NOT about public key authorization, I know how to copy the public key and ssh that way. This is about the private key.

So I just created 2 VMs, they're connected through vagrant private network. One of them is called server01 the other is called server02.

I created user '01' on 'server01', and user '02' on 'server02'.

I `ssh-keygen` on both of them, so they each have `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`.

I copy the contents of 01's `id_rsa` (the private key) into a file called `01key` in 02's machine.

I then ssh into 01 from 02 with the following command:
`ssh -i 01key 01@10.9.8.11`
And it asks me for the password....

Why? Isn't the whole point of connecting with the private key that you DON'T use passwords? I created a Linux server on AWS and it provided me with a private key for that particular instance and I was able to `ssh -I key` into it without it asking for the password, so what am I doing wrong?

I checked the permissions on the 01key file, and they're 600.

EDIT: All the answers are irrelevant. I know how to use the public key to connect through ssh, but that's not what I'm looking for.

I created a Linux instance on AWS and created an ssh keypair, then it only gave me the PRIVATE key, which I could use to connect to that AWS instance. That's what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't supposed to copy the private key.  It's `id_rsa.pub` you want, and usually you would put that in `~02/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: Yes I was able to create a user called 01, and another called 02 on the other machine. The AWS server gave me it's private ssh key, which I used to connect to it without it asking for my password. I know how to ssh with the public key, with that method 02 would give his public key to 01 and append it to the `authorized_keys` file, and then 02 would connect to 01, but that's work on 01's part, which is not what happened on the AWS server.

Comment: Alright, I will be interested to read the answer if it's forthcoming.

Comment: Now that you have two additional answers not substantially different from mine, one from a user of high rep.

Answer (score 1):

> I copy the contents of 01's id_rsa (the private key) into a file called 01key in 02's machine.

Pubkey authentication doesn't work like that. You must copy user01's **public** key to

```
~user01/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

on server02. This is more easily done via the command:

```
ssh-copy-id user01@server02
```

> I then ssh into 01 from 02 ...

That's the opposite, with this setup you can ssh **from** server01 to server02 passwordlessly.

> ... with the following command: ssh -I 01key 01@10.9.8.11

The `-I` flag specifies the PKCS#11 shared library. You probably meant `-i` to specify the identity. Anyway, this is unnecessary; just do

```
ssh user01@server02
```

Comment: I know how to use the pubkey to connect. I know how to use the ssh-copy-id command. The `I` was a typo. This does not answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

To copy the public key to a server use:

`ssh-copy-id user2@server`

wich will copy (on current server):

`/home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

into the file (on specified server):

`/home/user2/.ssh/authorized_keys`

This can also be done manually by appending public key:

`cat /home/user1/.ssh/id_pub.rsa | ssh user2@server "cat >> /home/user2/.ssh/authorized_keys"`

- `cat /home/user1/.ssh/id_pub.rsa` pipes contents of user1's public key
- `ssh user2@server "[cmd]"` execute specified command as user2 on specified server
- `cat >> /home/user2/.ssh/authorized_keys` takes piped data and appends to file